# Is it possible to bypass a proxy when the proxy settings are set to Auto Proxy Config?

Tags: dns, proxy, rails

I've set up Automatic Proxy Configuration (PAC) in OSX Snow Leopard to point to a URL. I've also filled out the "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains" box because I want to skip the proxy for certain sites. (I'm using [pow](http://pow.cx/) which as far as I understand, works by creating a local mini dns server.)

If I use Apple's Web Proxy/Secure Web Proxy, it'll use my settings for bypassing the proxy, but apparently not for PAC. Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran into this as well and it doesn't seem to apply the "bypass" sites when using the auto proxy settings. I suppose that is the intended behavior, otherwise it wouldn't be very "automatic".

I just entered the proxy settings  manually and it worked for me.